# Skip FormsAuthenticationTicket expiration for Get/Post Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

In my web application (mvc 4 c #), I apply the FormsAuthenticationTicket expired after 30 minutes. After 30 minutes if the user does not do anything will be redirected to the login page.

But it did not happen in my dashboard page that there is automatic background post / get via Ajax (runs every 2 minutes).

FormsAuthenticationTicket in the dashboard page will never expired even if the user does not do anything (idle).

Is this caused by automatic background process (get / post Ajax), because the other pages will redirect to login if user idle

If yes, what should I do so that the background process does not affect the session expiration if the user idle?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to inherit the controller that receives the Ajax calls from ApiController.